# Javascript function inside a function access

Tags: javascript, function, object

how can I access a function inside a function? Here's an example:

```js
function fun1() {
  //some code here
  var example = function (){
    //some code here
  }
  return {
    example: example
  }
}
```

when i try to access it like this `fun1.example()` I get error **fun1.example is not a function.** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the outer function to get the return value: `fun1().example()` (and fix the syntax error).

Comment: The code as posted is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please look at comments for more info

```
function fun1() {
  //some code here
  var example = function () {
    //some code here
  };
  return {
    example: example,
  };
}
// Fun1 is funtion, In funtion there is no property like example

// So when you call fun1.example , which undefined. Is not a function
fun1.example() // Error here

const obj = fun1() // call funtion to get obj

obj.example() // No error
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to run the code as fun().example(), or store the result of fun() into a variable and then run it, like this:

```
var fun = ();
fun.example();
```